# AWS NLB warning: There is an Internet Gateway attached to these subnets

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-api-gateway, elastic-load-balancer

I am relatively new to AWS.  I've been able to:

- Setup edge-optimized API Gateway endpoints (w/a custom domain ... install an SSL cert, etc.)
- Route requests from API Gateway to a server running on an EC2 instance via HTTP proxy

For learning, I'd like to put a Network Load Balancer (NLB) between API Gateway and the EC2 instance.  After that, I want to experiment with Auto-Scaling Groups (in order to see how EC2 instances can be scaled out/in).

**BUT** I'm stuck on the NLB.  After adding it in, requests made to API Gateway endpoints simply return `internal server error`.

**Question**

Should I be using an `internal` or `internet-facing` NLB to route the requests from API Gateway to the EC2 instances?

- When I opt to use an `internal` NLB, I get a warning message `You are creating an internal Load Balancer, but there is an Internet Gateway attached to these subnets` ... and then I run into the `internal server error` problem.
- When I setup an `internet-facing` NLB, API Gateway warns me something to the effect of, "Your NLB is already public-facing, so the use of a VPC Link might be unnecessary".

Can someone shed some light on what I should be doing?

[image]

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Also what is the purpose of both the API Gateway and ELB? CloudFront can talk directly to the ELB right?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to create a NLB in a private subnet and create a VPC link. Private Subnets use network address translation (NAT) gateways, not internet gatways.
Link: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-nat-gateway.html

*NLB*
[image]

*VPCLink*
[image]